# Clarification regarding hint given for showing $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that the polynomial $p(x) = x^{4} - 4x^{2} + 8x + 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$.

Following a series of hints given by my textbook, I start by using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-2})$ is a unique factorization domain. So then by a corollary to Gauss' Lemma, I observe that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ iff it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Suppose $p(x)$ has a linear factor $x - \alpha$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. My hint says that I should be able to infer that $\alpha$ is a divisor of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ (this is obvious) and then conclude that $\alpha \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm \sqrt{-2}\}$. What I don't get is how it even makes sense to consider that $\alpha = \pm \sqrt{-2}$ in the integer field?

Comment: You probably want to consider ${\bf Z}[\sqrt {-2}]$, not ${\bf Z}(\sqrt{-2})$... I'm not even sure what the latter is supposed to mean.

Comment: You're right. I'll fix that. I was just copy/pasting the code.

Comment: Also, you probably meant the integer *ring*, not field? And who says $\alpha$ is an integer? I don't really understand the question...

Comment: You need to use the rational root theorem, but in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt-2]$, so that any roots are factors of $\pm 2/1$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need rational root theorem, just an elementary observation (which is part of the proof of the rational root theorem).

Notice that if $p(\alpha)=0$, then $\alpha(-\alpha^3+4\alpha-8)=2$, and the only factors of $2$ in the ring are the ones you listed.